# Find distance between two points using MKMapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, distance, euclidean-distance

I'm attempting to find the euclidean distance in meters between two points on an MKMapView using iPhone OS 3.2. The problem is that I have these coordinates in terms of latitude and longitude, which, mathematically provides me enough data to find the distance, but it's going to take some tricky trigonometry. Is there any simpler solution?

Thanks!

Comment: [The math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) doesn't look that difficult... What kind of simpler solution are you imagining?

Comment: The math is complex given that the earth is not flat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CLLocation` has a method to calculate the distance for you:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

API docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html).