# Google map or matrix api and tableview

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, core-location

THanks in advance for taking a min reading my questions here. I am developing a map app which uses mapkit, corelocation and google map api (ios) at the moment. So here is my question: Is that possible to use google map api to return distances from result locations to user' current location? The effect i wanna achieve is to make a tableview which lists my google map api search results (hospital locations) and sort them in the sequence of distance (close to far). There should also be a distance displayed in each cell. sorry i don't have enough credits to post pics.. so here is effect i wanna achieve: [Sending API Data to UITableView Within ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143428/sending-api-data-to-uitableview-within-viewcontroller)

So far i have managed to pull data from map api, put pins on the map and fill those search results into my tableview. I have done a lot of search but so far i haven't seen any article about using google map api to return distance.

BTW, I am really a newbee in iOS and google map api. I have also notice there is a google distance matrix api but i ain't sure how to use it in iOS. is that actually the api i need to use to find out the distance? it doesn't seems to have any packet to import.. the google's tutorial is not clear

P.S.  the data i got from map api is in json format and it contains latitude and longitude. i saved them in an array

Thanks again for the help

hey guys. I have figured out how to calculate the distance but i have no idea how to display it. here is my code block for distance calculating

```
enter code here -(void)putPins:(NSArray *)data {
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPins class]]) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++){
    NSDictionary* place = [data objectAtIndex:i];
    // 3 - There is a specific NSDictionary object that gives us the location info.
    NSDictionary *geo = [place objectForKey:@"geometry"];
    // Get the lat and long for the location.
    NSDictionary *loc = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];
    // 4 - Get your name and address info for adding to a pin.
    NSString *name=[place objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *vicinity=[place objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
           // Create a special variable to hold this coordinate info.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
    // Set the lat and long.
    placeCoord.latitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    placeCoord.longitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
    // 5 - Create a new annotation.
    MapPins *placeObject = [[MapPins alloc] initWithName:name address:vicinity coordinate:placeCoord];
    [mapView addAnnotation:placeObject];

    //test methods
     CLLocation *locationA = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:currentCentre.latitude longitude:currentCentre.longitude];
    CLLocation *locationB = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:placeCoord.latitude longitude:placeCoord.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];
            NSLog(@"distance in meters=%f",distanceInMeters);

    NSString *distanceD = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",distanceInMeters];

}
```

}

the last line, NSString *distanceD i tried to put the distanceInMeters into a NSString format and somehow display it. but it turned out not working at all. I can't put it inot the mappin method. (error saying undeclared..)

Answer (score 0):

So since you have the latitude and longitude coordinates of the point you are trying to compare to, and since you're comparing to your current location, you should be able to do something similar to this question:

[Find distance between two points using MKMapKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065967/find-distance-between-two-points-using-mkmapkit)

All you'd have to do is calculate that distance for each row in your cell, and then you'd have a CLLocationDistance object per row to work with.

Comment: Hi @BHendricks, thanks for the reply. but my problem here is that i fetch the json file by using the google map api url request. so i have to use the "for key" function to reach latitude and longitude each time. i am quite confused how to use apple's location method with these json data. Is there a way that i can let the api sort out those distances and give me a reply in json file and i can fill them into my tableview?

Comment: I don't think that that is possible, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: hey guys i just found out a method maybe useful for me :CLLocationDistance distance = [firstLocation distanceFromLocation:secondLocation]; but my problem here will be what to put into the firstlocaiton and the secondlocation. i just saved the locaiton name, lat and long into an array. all data is from google. but seems i need to get the lat and long values out separately and.... seriously i got no idea how to do it. thanks for the help guys

Comment: That is the method I was recommending you use. Basically, with each lat/long value you get, you need to create a CLLocation. Then, you can use the aforementioned method to generate a CLLocationDistance.

Comment: hey BHendricks, cheers. but i totally have no idea what to do at the moment. will you please have a look at my code? i will send it to you if you can give me a email add. thanks a lot

Comment: Are you able to get individual lat/long values from your JSON?

Comment: hey BHendricks, i have managed calculating the distance. I can see all distance calculated in the debugger (by using NSLog) but I coded the method inside another. so i cant really find a way to display it. I will post the block of code by 2 parts. sorry i can't post the code in one go (too many characters). thanks for the help

Comment: Now I'm confused as to what you're trying to do with the distances. Are you successfully getting a CLLocationDistance?

Comment: did you see the code i just uploaded? I have managed calculating the distance from each locations i fetched from g map to user's location. but i did this inside the method named "putPins". I can see the distance results in the debugger since i used NSLog but i can't find a way of displaying these distance in the UI. The ideal place i wanna to put the distance is at the right end of each table cell. can you pls have a look into the code? i guess i may have to make the variable global but i have no idea how